# Convert query to D7 for db_query_range

Tags: 7, database

How do I convert the query below properly to 7x?

```
$query = db_query('SELECT latitude, longitude FROM {zipcodes} WHERE city = UPPER("%s") LIMIT 1', $search_term);
```

```
$query = db_query('SELECT latitude, longitude FROM {zipcodes} WHERE zip = "%s" LIMIT 1', $search_term);
```

The Coder module advised that I change it to db_query_range so I tried the code below.

```
$query = db_query_range('SELECT z.latitude, z.longitude FROM {zipcodes} z WHERE z.city = UPPER(:city)', 0, 1, array(':city' => $search_term);
```

```
$query = db_query_range('SELECT z.latitude, z.longitude FROM {zipcodes} z WHERE z.zip = :zip', 0, 1, array(':zip' => $search_term);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell your code is fine except for a small syntax error; you're missing a closing parenthesis on the end of the statement. It should be:

```
$query = db_query_range('SELECT z.latitude, z.longitude FROM {zipcodes} z WHERE z.city = UPPER(:city)', 0, 1, array(':city' =>$search_term));
```

It's often handy to split the arguments out into a separate array so this sort of thing is easily avoidable:

```
$args = array(':city' => $search_term);
$query = db_query_range('SELECT z.latitude, z.longitude FROM {zipcodes} z WHERE z.city = UPPER(:city)', 0, 1, $args);
```